# Working code returns run-time error '-2147352571 (80020005)'

Tags: excel, vba

As so many others in here i'm a rookie at VBA trying to make some nice QOL improvements at my new job.

Hence i tried to add a button that would extend a small table (not formatted as table though) and keep the formatting and formulas. And I actually succeded (atleast a little bit) and the button works as intended. Therefore it was a surprise to me, that when i run the code in the VBA editor, it gives me **"run-time error '-2147352571 (80020005)'"**

As you can probably understand i do not like this, and would like to solve it before shipping the spreadsheet out to the intended users.

My code is as follows:

```
Sub Name_of_code ()
    Dim b As Object, cs As Integer
    Set b = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    With b.TopLeftCell.EntireRow.Offset(-2, 0)
.Insert
.Cells(1, 2).Copy .Cells(0, 2)
.Cells(1, 3).Copy .Cells(0, 3)
.Cells(1, 4).Copy .Cells(0, 4)

    End With
End Sub
```

And the table looks like this. Its a small table used to show purchase orders. The object used as trigger is just an icon inserted from the excel-icons.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9KNn.png)

I get the error at line 3 (" `Set b = ActiveSheet......`). Here's a pic of the debug result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZNQM.png)

I really can't seem to figure out, what the problem is.

Please help me :)

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I've been made aware that i should clarify if its a cross-post so:
This is a cross-post on mrexcel.com aswell. (sorry for any inconvenience)
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-code-working-but-giving-run-time-error-2147352571-80020005.1184681/#post-5771449

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the value of `Application.Caller`? As it is triggered by an icon, it might not return the name of a shape, hence [`ActiveSheet.Shapes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes) can't return a `Shape` object. Try this:

```
Dim b As Shape, cs As Integer, callingShape As String

On Error Goto ErrHandler

callingShape = Application.Caller
Debug.Print "Application.Caller: "; callingShape

If callingShape = "<Insert right name here>" Then
    
    Set b = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    With b.TopLeftCell.EntireRow.Offset(-2, 0)
        .Insert
        .Cells(1, 2).Copy .Cells(0, 2)
        .Cells(1, 3).Copy .Cells(0, 3)
        .Cells(1, 4).Copy .Cells(0, 4)
    End With
    
Else
    MsgBox callingShape & " doesn't appear to be a Shape."
End If

ErrExit:
    On Error Goto 0
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Error # " & CStr(Err.Number) & ", " & Err.Description & " occured."
    Err.Clear
    Resume ErrExit
```

Comment: Hello. And thanks for your response. I tried your code. When i use my button with your code assigned to it, i get the error code "Graphic X doesn't appear to be a Shape", and if i go to VBE i get the error "Error # 13, Type mismatch occured".

What can i do now? I must admit that i dont completely understand your code, as i'm pretty new at VBA, and i have only made som few simple codes myself or edited some recorded codes so far..

Comment: At least we confirmed my suspicion that `Application.Caller` is in fact **not** a Shape (item name). But I'm not familiar with Excel's objects, so I can't make a useful suggestion as to how you should continue. Let's wait until a real Excel expert checks in. I'm sure the solution isn't that hard, just so I'm not knowledgable enough in Excel.

Comment: Thank you very much anyway :-) I was also wondering why such a "simple" code could be bugged, if it was not this, but i also have no idea how to fix it unfortunately.